# Everything Was Fine Then Brushes stopped affecting mesh

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I was sculpting my first ever object in blender. It was working fine no issues, then i switched between object & edit modes and came back to sculpt mode when applied my brushes those did not affected my mesh. I checked all settings again if everything is correct like Dyntopo, Start and end clipping, symmetry, Brush stroke, Brush Radius everything was selected and enabled. I surfed through internet for to find out people facing same issue to solve my problem. but could not.
Maybe, i am still wrong at something. If you guys [check my file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjl7tnwoceens3f/First%20Scul%5Bpt.blend?dl=0) and see through that would be the most help for me today.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've masked the whole surface, you can't sculpt on the masked surface, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to unmask.

Comment: Thank you, it helped! It is so dumb of me applying mask and then forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do sculpting, so can't help much...
But here's a video where it explains how to configure the hot keys of each of your brushes so they work correctly:
https://youtu.be/eGuDCgU_4os

And this is an old video that solves some common problems of sculpting:
https://youtu.be/DAdYQ4xpNo0

If nothing of the above helps, then save your project file, and try uninstalling and reinstalling blender again, or use a portable (zip) version of blender... Then open your file and check if the brushes are working again

Comment: Hi. Link-only answers are discouraged, if the link goes down so 
does the answer. Please help us making this site a real 
knowledgebase and add all relevant steps to your answer. Thanks.